# Incompatible shapes: [64,4,4] vs. [64,4] - Time Series with 4 variables as input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, lstm

I am trying to train a LSTM Autoencoder with multivariate time series data. The shape of data is:

```
print(X_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)
print(y_test.shape)

(160573, 4, 4)
(160573, 4)
(17838, 4, 4)
(17838, 4)
```

I wanted to transfer my model for univariate time series into a model for multivariate time series but somehow I do not know what to change:

```
model = keras.Sequential()

model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(
    units=64,
    input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])
))

model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2))
model.add(keras.layers.RepeatVector(n=X_train.shape[1]))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=True))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2))
model.add(
  keras.layers.TimeDistributed(
    keras.layers.Dense(units=X_train.shape[2])
  )
)

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

training = model.fit(
    X_train, y_train,
    epochs=10,
    batch_size=64,
    validation_split=0.1,
    shuffle=False

)
```

The error is:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [64,4,4] vs. [64,4]
     [[node gradient_tape/mean_squared_error/BroadcastGradientArgs (defined at <ipython-input-83-6205cceab3d0>:1) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_96522]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

Is there any solution for multivariate time series?

Thank you and best,
Can

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're not trying to predict a sequence, you need to remove `return_sequences=True` to remove the time step. Same goes for the `TimeDistributed` layer, remove it.

Corrected, minimal example:

```
import os
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

X_train = np.random.rand(160, 4, 4)
y_train = np.random.rand(160, 4)
X_test = np.random.rand(17, 4, 4)
y_test = np.random.rand(17, 4)

model = keras.Sequential()

model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(
    units=4,
    input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])
))

model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2))
model.add(keras.layers.RepeatVector(n=X_train.shape[1]))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(units=4))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=X_train.shape[2]))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

training = model.fit(
    X_train, y_train,
    epochs=1,
    batch_size=8,
    validation_split=0.1,
    shuffle=False)
```

Comment: Hi Nicolas, thank you for your answer. The model is working but how can I calculate my losses when I have X_train = 160,4,4 and X_train_predicted = 160,4?

Comment: your loss will be calculated between `y_train` and `X_train_predicted`, so the shapes will match